# Python form handling

Tags: python, html, forms, post

Could anyone help me find the problem in my Python script? This script simply gets a request posted from an HTML form with a few radio buttons.

```
import cgi
from file import *
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print """<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">"""

print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">"
print "<title></title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"

choice = form.getvalue('option')

f = File("onlineVotes.txt")

if choice is None:
    print "<p class='error'>Please choose an option before voting.</p>"
    print "<br><a href='onlinePoll.html' class='backVoteAgain'>Go back</a>"

else:
    if f.exists() == False:
        f.startWrite()
        f.write(choice)
        print choice
        print "<div class='voteBar' style='width: 250px;'>"
        print 1
        print "</div>"

    else:
        f.startRead()
        choice = f.read() + " " + choice
        choiceList = choice.split()

        filterList = []

        for item in choiceList:
            if item not in filterList:
                filterList.append(item)

        choiceDict = {}

        for elem in filterList:
            print "<br>" + elem

            counts = choiceList.count(elem)

            choiceDict['%s' % elem] = counts
            maxValue = max(choiceDict.values())

            barWidth = counts*250/maxValue

            print "<div class='voteBar' style='width: %spx;'>" % str(barWidth)
            print counts
            print maxValue
            print "</div>"

        totalVotes = str(sum(choiceDict.values()))
        print "<br>Total number of votes: " + totalVotes

    f.startWrite()
    f.write(choice)
    f.close()

print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

The problem with this is that when option1 gets 10 votes, option2 gets 5 votes and option3 gets 3 votes, the value of max(choiceDict.values()) is 10, which is good as expected. However, when option1 gets 10 votes, option2 gets 11 votes and option3 gets 5 votes, the max value for option1 stays at 10 while it is 11 for both option2 and option3.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `choiceDict.values()` for the case in which you don't get the expected result?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out! So for option1 it's [10], option2 is [10, 5], option3 is [10, 5, 3]. Now I see the problem, but how do I solve it? I was thinking of taking choiceDict.values() outside of the for loop, but I need it to calculate the width inside of the loop as well..

Comment: It looks like `choiceDict` isn't fully populated after the `filterList` loop is finished. I think you first need to insert all values and, after that, render html. Otherwise, you won't get the same output for each iteration.